# What are the conditions of the query in order to be True?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and trying to figure out how it works. So could anyone help me with the following code:

```
whatisthis([]).
whatisthis([_, b| L]):- whatisthis(L).
```

So when would Prolog return 'True' if the query would have the following format:

`?- whatisthis(X).`

I experimented with some different inputs and the only X that returned 'True' was X = [].

Comment: Why not just run the query without giving it a specific input, but a variable? It will tell you all of the values of `X` that make it true!

Answer (score 2):

This query is even that declarative that you can query what `X` will be true:

```
?- whatisthis(X).
X = [] ;
X = [_G1242, b] ;
X = [_G1242, b, _G1248, b] ;
X = [_G1242, b, _G1248, b, _G1254, b] ;
X = [_G1242, b, _G1248, b, _G1254, b, _G1260, b] ;
X = [_G1242, b, _G1248, b, _G1254, b, _G1260, b, _G1266|...]
```

If you hit the semicolon <kbd>;</kbd> it will emit the next result. The `_Gxxxx` parts are *unbound* variables. You can write anything there.

So every `X` that is a ***list of even length where every second element is a `b`***. So the following examples will succeed:

```
[]
[a, b]
[2, b]
[1, b, 4, b]
[a, b, 1, b]
[f(a,b), b, b(f,a), b]
[1, b, 4, b, 2, b, 5, b]
```